# Asp.Net Claims Based authorization multiple objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

I see lots of examples some even with great details on how to apply claim based authorization for resources.

Unfortunately, all are aimed to a specific resource so you do something like :

```
GetEntity(int id) 
CheckAccess(id, user);
```

Then in few examples I see the permission/claim for the action

```
GetEntities()
```

where you have a true or false access to the result view. (which is ok)

What I don't seem to find or understand, is how on a `GetEntities` action, I can return a list of entites and get the permission of the data using claims.

Practical example:

I have a shared address book for some X users in some group.

So group 1 have contact A, B, C

user 10 have permission to list contacts of group 1
user 10 have permission to see full details of contact A and B
user 10 have permission to see basic details of contact C

So I will end up showing in the view something like :

Contact A: name, phone and address
Contact B: name, phone and address
Contact C: name only.

Another thing is not quite clear, is where in the database should I store and how claims so I can later filter the result set from the database.

Let's say user 9 don't have permission to list contacts of group 1 but 2.
How is this claim stored and used to filter results on query ?

I know this is a pretty basic question, but i just don't get it!